# Why is Outlook for Android using a weird From address?

Tags: email, outlook

My wife uses Outlook.com for her email and has an alias assigned from a domain we own.  The alias is the default address. Works great while she is using Outlook.com.

She also uses Outlook for Android (OFA) on the Samsung Galaxy Edge 7. She's signed into the same account, but when she goes to compose an email, the From shows as an odd outlook_398f6...@outlook.com address instead of her alias.

In the drop down of aliases in OFA, her normal outlook.com address appears along with the weird one, but the alias from our domain is not displayed.

Last odd fact is in the OFA account settings, the Account Name is actually listed as our domain alias account.

What I've done.

- Swapped the default aliases a couple times on Outlook.com
- Reset the account in OFA
- Removed and added the account on OFA
- Uninstalled and reinstalled OFA

Comment: Does this "weird" address also appear on Outlook.com? Have you tried sending an email to your other personal account and checked the From field? My current wild a** guess is that Outlook for Android doesn't support custom domain and that "weird" address is actually the same alias on Outlook.com

Comment: On the second thought, are you asking only about the weird From address, or also if an alias is supported on Outlook for Android? Because the answer to the latter seems to be: no, it's not supported ([AndroidCentral forum](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/671813-outlook-app-aliases.html), [official feature request](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293346-outlook-for-android/suggestions/9559287-alias-support)), though it seems someone did succeed. ([AndroidForums](https://androidforums.com/threads/solved-outlook-android-app-default-email-reply-to-address-where-is-it.1070842/))

Comment: I assume the address is an internal alias to the custom domain address.

Comment: I guess the question is whether it is supported.  I'm pretty certain it has worked for her in the past, but reviewing the item to referenced, it appears that it does not work now.